# Firebase: Email verification and user login to be able to access the page

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularjs-directive, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I have created a form "main.html#!/register" to allow users to enter their: firstname, lastname, email and login. Once all those entered an email verification is sent, so that they cannot get to the page "main.html#!/success" before verifying the email.

**The good news is**: If they try to get to the access page from the login page without confirming the Email, they will not be able to access.
**The bad news is**: Right after the registration, if they enter the "main.html#!/success" they will be able to open this page !!

Use case:
The user is not able to access to "main.html#!/success" without any registration
The user is not able to access the "main.html#!/success" from the login page "main.html#!/login", if he has not verified his email
The problem is : The user is able to access the "main.html#!/success" right after the registration without email confirmation.

**Question**:
How can I use the email verification condition *user.emailVerified* and the user auth *$requireSignIn()* to allow the access to the page "main.html#!/success" ?
I had put a resolve function to prevent any access without the registration.

Here is my codes
1-resolve function:
Authentication is a service I have created

```
 when('/success', {
  templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
  controller: 'SuccessController',
  resolve: {
    currentAuth: function(Authentication) {
    return Authentication.requireAuth();
    } //currentAuth
  }//resolve
}).
```

2-code in the Authentication service

```
requireAuth: function() {
    return auth.$requireSignIn();
}, //require Authentication
```

3- the register function (it is in the service)

```
register: function(user) {   
  auth.$createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    user.email,
    user.password
  ).then(function(regUser) {
    var regRef = ref.child('users')
      .child(regUser.uid).set({
        date: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        regUser: regUser.uid,
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        email: user.email 
      }); //userinfo
    regUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
      // Email sent.
        alert("your Email is verified: " + regUser.emailVerified) ;
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
        alert(error);
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    $rootScope.message = error.message;
  }); //createUserWithEmailAndPassword
} //register
```

3- login function

```
login: function(user) {
            auth.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            user.email,
            user.password
          ).then(function(user) {
                if(user.emailVerified){
                  $location.path('/success');
                }
                else{
                $rootScope.message= "Please validate your registration first : "+user.emailVerified;
                }
          }).catch(function(error) {
            $rootScope.message = error.message;
          }); //signInWithEmailAndPassword
}, //login
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to enforce this on the client side. Instead you should enforce access for verified signed in users from your Firebase rules. For example:

`".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified == true"`

Comment: Thank you bojeil, but since I added this rules, no user data is getting added into the db..!! weird

Comment: Another question: once I set up this rule, what should I put in the login() in the client side ? for the moment the validations is done in the client side.

Comment: Well, I just noiticed that because of the rule : ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid && auth.token.email_verified == true" the user's data is not created into the DB

Comment: Ah yeah, they won't get added because the user is not verified at that time you populate the db node. You could relax that node rule to allow the logged in user but you would need to apply the additional restrictive rule for data that only verified can access.